# install command in makefile

Tags: makefile

Iam getting some error while installing executable in `/usr/local/bin` thru makefile:

```
install -m 755 my_execble /usr/local/bin
```

install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/bin/my_execble`: Permission denied

If use sudo before 'install' command .. 
then it will work .. but is there other way of installing without using sudo?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the makefile.

Answer (score 6):

The OP ask long time ago, but I will guess it can be useful for others.

Since your `make install` command try to install files in directory requiring *root privileges* (ex: /usr/local/bin) you can either:

- Become root before launching your command (as you stated in your description: using `sudo` for example)

OR

- Install it in another directory that do not require specific privilege. For this purpose you can use a specific parameter named 'DESTDIR' that is usually supported in makefile, so that your command looks like:

  `make DESTDIR=/home/myuser/my_dest_dir install`

  This is named [Staged Installs](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can either tweak the Makefile (or use a configure script) to have it install the program in your home directory... or become root.